# From independence to conditional independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Consider three random variables $X,Y,Z$. Suppose $X\perp Z$ and $Y\perp Z$, where $\perp $ denotes independence.

Is it true that ($X\perp Y$) implies ($X\perp Y$ conditional on $Z$)? I know that in general independence does not imply conditional independence, but I was wondering whether the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent of $Z$ simplifies things.

Comment: No.  Say you are tossing two fair coins. $X$ is the event "the first coin comes up $H$".  $Y$ is the event "the second coin comes up $H$".  $Z$ is the event "the two coins come up the same"

Comment: Is in your example $X$ independent of $Z$?

Comment: Of course.  Knowing that the two coins match doesn't tell me what the first coin came up.

Comment: OK, what additional condition I would need to go from independence to conditional independence?

Comment: Well, you could just assume conditional independence.  Not sure there's some natural intermediate assumption....

Comment: Thank you.. I am trying to figure out an answer for my question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254461/conditionally-independent-binary-random-variables but I am stuck at independence versus conditional independence.

Comment: @lulu Another question related to your example: take $X$, $Y$ and $Z$  independent of each other. Since $X$ and $Y$ are both independent of $Z$ and of each other, we can say that the vector $(X,Y)$ is independent of $Z$. Is this true in your example? It does not seem so... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Clearly you can't say that $(X,Y)$ is independent of $Z$. If you are unsure, write out all the probabilities. Knowing $Z$, I claim that $X=H$ with probability $\frac 12$.  Can you prove that?

Comment: I looked at your other question...as with this one, I don't think anything is true in general.  As far as I can see I am free to take $X=Y$ and $w(Z_1,Z_2)=\frac 12$.  Or I can take $X,Y$ independent.  I don't see any restrictions.

Comment: OK, regarding the proof, I can think in this way: given the random variables $X,Y,Z$ with $X \perp Y$, $X\perp Z$, $Y\perp Z$, we have $f_{X|Z}=f_X$, $f_{Y|Z}=f_Y$, $f_{X,Y}=f_X \times f_Y=f_{X|Z} \times f_{Y|Z}$ which is not necessarily $f_{X,Y|Z}$.

Comment: @lulu could you write some comments (or an answer) below my other question? From what you wrote here, I guess the two mistakes that you pointed out by helping me with this other question are: (1) $A_X$, $A_Y$, $A_Q$ are not necessarily independent of each other and (2) even if $A_X$, $A_Y$, $A_Q$ were independent, it would not imply that $X\perp Y|Z_1,Z_2, Z_3, Z_4$ and similar.

Comment: No time, sorry.  I expect my counterexample to this problem is also a counterexample to the other...but I didn't read it carefully enough to be certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well known that there exist events $A,B,C$ such that any two of them are independent but $P(A\cap B\cap C) \neq P(A)P(B)P(C)$. Take $X=I_A.Y=I_B,Z=I_C$ to get a  counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

$X\perp Y | Z$ implies that $p(X \cap Y|Z) = p(X|Z)p(Y|Z)$.

And further we can obtain:

$$\begin{align}
\begin{array}{rc}
X\perp Y | Z 
\implies&  
p(X \cap Y|Z) = p(X|Z)p(Y|Z) \\ 
\implies&  
\frac{p(X \cap Y|Z)}{p(Y|Z)}=p(X|Z) \\
\implies& 
p(X|Y,Z) = p(X|Z)
\end{array}
\end{align}$$

And if $X \perp Z$, $Y\perp Z$ and $X\perp Y$ we can get:

$$\begin{align}
p(X|Y,Z) &= \frac{p(X, Y, Z)}{p(X,Z)} \\ 
& = \frac{p(X)p(Y|X)p(Z|Y, X)}{p(X)p(Z|X)} \\
& = \frac{p(Y)p(Z|X,Y)}{p(Z)}
\end{align}$$

So the first case $X \perp Z$, $Y\perp Z$ and $X\perp Y$ cannot imply the second $X\perp Y | Z$.

I hope the above reduction and reasoning hold.